# Taking four items instead of on in a for loop

Tags: python

I have an array of bytes and what I want to do is take four bytes from the array, do something with it and then take the next four bytes. Is it at all possible to do this is a list comprehension or make a for loop take four items from the array instead of one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is using itertools

http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html

by using the grouper() method

```
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def clumper(s, count=4):
    for x in range(0, len(s), count):
        yield s[x:x+count]

>>> list(clumper("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))
['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl', 'mnop', 'qrst', 'uvwx', 'yz']
>>> list(clumper("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 5))
['abcde', 'fghij', 'klmno', 'pqrst', 'uvwxy', 'z']
```

Comment: Using `range` is correct only if you're using Python 3 (and it's not clear whether the OP wants something *just* for Py3k or also for 2). In Python 2, `range` creates a list full of integers, and you should use `xrange` instead to return an iterator.

Comment: The code works fine in both. Using range will still work in Python 2, it just might use more memory. But it will also probably run faster. I'd need to be processing sequences at least tens of millions of items long before I cared.

Comment: Why bother using a generator then?

Comment: Because I'd only need to be processing a sequence a few dozen thousand items long before I cared about making a list of lists of generic objects, compared to a list of ints.

Answer (score 2):

In one line

```
x="12345678987654321"
y=[x[i:i+4] for i in range(0,len(x),4)]
print y
```

Comment: I've been using Python for years now and I never knew `range` could take a third argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
suxmac2:Music ajung$ cat xx.py 
lst = range(20)

for i in range(0, len(lst)/4):
    print lst[i*4 : i*4+4]

suxmac2:Music ajung$ python2.5 xx.py
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6, 7]
[8, 9, 10, 11]
[12, 13, 14, 15]
[16, 17, 18, 19]
```